# recovering counts without revelaing patient data

Tags: privacy

[image: p1]
[image: p2 w questions]

i am reading about variants of binning and wondered if somene could explain problem 2.1 and 2.2 for me.

Comment: Please provide a reference for this text, and transcribe (at least the most relevant bits of) the questions.